# Determining unique child node count XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have searched around and found many posts on this site to be useful in getting me this far.

I am trying to use xslt to combine elements and their children that share a common attribute value.  I have managed to do this using xsl:keys.

The part that I am stuck on is I also need to essentially reproduce the original tree except if the parent element with a specific attribute matches the combined structure I am producing then the parent element should have no children.  You can see this in the example input/output provided.  The `<parent attribute="two"/>` in the second portion of the output has no children as it originally contained all of the children.

XML Input format:

```
<root>
    <parent attribute="one">
        <child>one</child>
        <child>two</child>
        <child>three</child>
    </parent>
    <parent attribute="two">
        <child>one</child>
        <child>two</child>
        <child>three</child>
    </parent>
    <parent attribute="one">
        <child>two</child>
        <child>three</child>
        <child>four</child>
    </parent>
    <extra>
        <extra>
            <parent attribute="two">
                <child>three</child>
            </parent>
        </extra>
    </extra>
</root>
```

Desired Output format:

```
<root>
    <first>
        <new attribute="one">
            <child>one</child>
            <child>two</child>
            <child>three</child>
            <child>four</child>
        </new>
        <new attribute="two">
            <child>one</child>
            <child>two</child>
            <child>three</child>
        </new>
    </first>
    <second>
        <parent attribute="one">
            <child>one</child>
            <child>two</child>
            <child>three</child>
        </parent>
        <parent attribute="two"/>
        <parent attribute="one">
            <child>two</child>
            <child>three</child>
            <child>four</child>
        </parent>
        <extra>
            <extra>
                <parent attribute="two">
                    <child>three</child>
                </parent>
            </extra>
        </extra>
    </second>
</root>
```

My current attempts involved reusing the keys created for the first section of the output.  My goal is to simply compare the total unique child count to the current parents child count to determine if the current parent node contains all of the combined child nodes.  I have tried many similar ways of producing this combined count as highlighted below but I am beginning to think I am tackling this problem incorrectly as I either am returning the count of every single child element or the count of the current parent elements children.

I have not looked into retaining the rest of the original structure for the second section as this was not the pressing issue at the time.

Any advice would be appreciated.  If I am bad at searching and someone else has had a similar question answered feel free to direct me there.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="ParentKey" match="parent" use="@attribute"/>
  <xsl:key name="ChildKey" match="parent/child" use="../@attribute"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="first">
      <xsl:for-each select="//parent[count(. | key('ParentKey', @attribute)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:element name="new">
          <xsl:attribute name="attribute">
            <xsl:value-of select="@attribute"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="child[count(. | key('ChildKey', @attribute)[1]) = 1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="second">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//parent" mode="second"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:element name="child">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent" mode="second">
    <xsl:element name="parent">
      <xsl:attribute name="attribute">
        <xsl:value-of select="@attribute"/>   
      </xsl:attribute>
      <!-- currently problematic line -->
      <xsl:variable name="combinedCount" select="count(//parent/child[count(. | key('ChildKey', @attribute)[1]) = 1])"/>
      <xsl:variable name="currentCount" select="count(child)"/>
      <xsl:if test="not($combinedCount = $currentCount)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For grouping problems in particular (but for all XSLT questions really) you need to make it clear whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. The solutions can be very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Muenchian Grouping, so I am assuming you are using XSLT 1.0 (As great as Muenchian Grouping is, there are easier ways to do grouping in XSLT 2.0).

But the main thing you need to change is your definition of the `ChildKey` as you are actually looking for distinct child elements for each possible parent attribute, so you need to define your key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="ChildKey" match="child" use="concat(../@attribute, '|', .)"/>
```

Then, your `combined` count variable is set as follows, to count the distinct child elements for the given parent attribute:

```
 <xsl:variable name="combinedCount" select="count(key('ParentKey', @attribute)/child[count(. | key('ChildKey', concat(../@attribute, '|', .))[1]) = 1])"/>
```

Try this XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="ParentKey" match="parent" use="@attribute"/>
  <xsl:key name="ChildKey" match="child" use="concat(../@attribute, '|', .)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <first>
          <xsl:for-each select="//parent[count(. | key('ParentKey', @attribute)[1]) = 1]">
            <new attribute="{@attribute}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="child[count(. | key('ChildKey', @attribute)[1]) = 1]"/>
            </new>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </first>
        <second>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </second>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <parent attribute="{@attribute}">
      <!-- currently problematic line -->
      <xsl:variable name="combinedCount" select="count(key('ParentKey', @attribute)/child[count(. | key('ChildKey', concat(../@attribute, '|', .))[1]) = 1])"/>
      <xsl:variable name="currentCount" select="count(child)"/>
      <xsl:if test="not($combinedCount = $currentCount)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </parent>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```